# Find the mean and variance of $S^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I found the mean and variance of Y by using the mgf, but how to get the mean and variance of S^2 now?

---

Let $Y = \frac {(n − 1)S^2}{σ^2}$ where $Y ∼ χ^2_{n−1}$ so that $S^2$ is the sample variance of an iid sample of $N(µ, σ^2)$ random variables. Noting that a $χ^2_v$ random variable has a moment generating function $M(t) = (1 − 2t)^{−v/2}$, show that the mean and variance of $Y$ are $n − 1$ and $2(n − 1)$ respectively. Hence or otherwise, find the mean and variance of $S^2$

Comment: $S^2$ is a linear function of $Y$, so you should be able to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^{2}_{n-1}$ , we get
$$\begin{align}
\Bbb E\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\right) & = \Bbb E(\chi^{2}_{n-1}) \\
\frac{(n-1)}{\sigma^2}\Bbb E(S^2) & = (n-1) \\
\Bbb E(S^2) & = \sigma^2
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\right) & = \text{Var}(\chi^{2}_{n-1}) \\
\frac{(n-1)^2}{\sigma^4}\text{Var}(S^2) & = 2(n-1) \\
\text{Var}(S^2) & =\frac{2\sigma^4}{(n-1)},
\end{align}$$

where we have used that fact that $\text{Var}(\chi^{2}_{n-1})=2(n-1)$ and $\Bbb E(\chi^{2}_{n-1})=n-1$.